# How to configure Jenkins job "Build trigger" so it triggers job based on creation of Dockerhub image with latest tag ONLY

Tags: docker, jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I'm using Build trigger phase to setup automatic triggering of Jenkins job execution when new image of specific repo is created on the Dockerhub.

It looks like this:
[image: Jenkins build trigger configuration]

Repositories text field from the picture, looks like this: **namespace/imagename**

I've setup a webhook on the Dockerhub side and this works well but in all these cases:

1. When Docker image with latest tag is created
2. When Docker image with any other tag is created

I want to restrict trigger of this job so it is triggered only when latest tag is created (**namespace/imagename:latest**) and I don't want to automatically run this job when, for example, version like (**namespace/imagename:v0.0.1**) is created.

I've tried setting in the "Repositories" text field: **namespace/imagename:latest** but in that case, nothing got triggered.

Is there some way to restrict which specific tag for the docker image will trigger Jenkins job?

Thanks

Comment: (Common advice, especially around Kubernetes, is to try to avoid using a `:latest` tag or any similar fixed string, and to prefer a unique tag per build.  This helps avoid ambiguity around _which_ "latest" build you actually have; if you `docker run namespace/imagename` and there is already a build locally, it will just use it, but if you `docker run ...:v0.0.1` it will pull a new build if needed.)

Comment: You may want to programmatically explore what triggered the build, and if it's triggered by the image change that doesn't fit what you want, end the job.